# OpenCV: Stitch with saving warping/arrangement informations and re-stitch with the saved info

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

First of all, I am a beginner in computer vision field, learning OpenCV from the web.

What I am trying is stitching multispectral (bands > 3) images with OpenCV stitching APIs.

I already know that OpenCV doesn't support multispectral image.

So, the idea I came up with is as follows:

1. Extract the RGB images from each multispectral image.
2. Use cv2.Stitcher_create() and stitcher.stitch class to stitch all the RGB images (reference: https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/17/image-stitching-with-opencv-and-python/). And save the warping and arrangement informations (ex. Homography, matching keypoints...) in making RGB panorama.
3. Stitch each remaining bands' image by loading the informations that saved in step 2.

The problem is, I can't find the codes for the saving and loading informations that required in step 2 and 3.

Is the suggested method possible? And if possible, is there any tips or references that I can use?

Comment: Why do you need that information once you have stitched the images?  You could consider using PCA to reduce the number of channels to 3. Stitch the 3 PCA channels. Those channels will contain the 3 highest information channels. Then convert those stitched PCA channels back to BGR form. See for example https://learnopencv.com/principal-component-analysis/ and https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/principal-component-analysis-for-image-data and https://towardsdatascience.com/principal-component-analysis-in-depth-understanding-through-image-visualization-892922f77d9f about PCA

Comment: PCA is a good solution! Thanks. I'll try it. But what I'm concerned about is that pixel values are tempered by interpolation during warping, so inverse-PCAed image will be slightly different from the original image.

Comment: Reverse PCA will be somewhat different from your original since you have fewer channels and less information. So what have you to lose by trying. If you have to have very accurate results, then you will need to stitch channel by channel and then combine channels as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it (I did it before for my paper on stitching construction plans). You need to save the camera parameters after the feature matching and probably also the seam masks.

Look [here (cameras)](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md#camera-estimation-adjustion-and-correction) and [here (seam masks)](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md#seam-masks)